# Ignoring android large text settings changes in android application?

Tags: android, textview, setting, large-text

Currently, I've broken UI when large text is enable in setting accessibility. Is there a tag in manifest or any other solution, to ignore textsize increase and decrease in TextView after check & uncheck large text in accessibility setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore large text option with providing text size in "dp" units not in "sp".

Comment: I did exactly same thing but it affect textsize in tablet. Is there another better solution?

Comment: By default, without changing any of the font size preferences, 1sp is equivalent to 1dp (also, they are equivalent before the preference was introduced). So probably on tablet you have changed some text preferences.